# How to write a file with PHP in Linux?

Tags: php, file

I want to write text file using PHP.

I can write it using fopen and fwrite function on Windows platform. But, that program is not able to write it on Linux Platform.

Is there any solution?

Comment: What is the error? May be you need to give 'write' rights to folder where you are creating file.

Comment: Have you chmodded the folder where you're writing ?

Comment: I hope , that you named the files correctly (or atleast the path you passed was relative)

Comment: Could you provide us some sample code? And what is 'that program' that you are referring to?

Comment: there are solutions, but first you have to find where the problem is ... check if you can write in the desired directory

Comment: How do you open the file with `fopen()`? You need at least the `r+` or any other than `r` mode to write to an file, because else its opened read-only.

Comment: I have written fopen with 'a' parameter.

Comment: @Ozzone: Then show us your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fopen` and `fwrite` work exactly the same on Linux, but you may have a permission issue there. To solve this, you need to check:

- the user under which PHP runs (in a vanilla Apache/PHP install, this is usually `www-data`)
- the permissions and ownership of the directory you are trying to write to

What you need is write permission on the directory for the PHP/Apache user. The easiest (and dirtiest) way of achieving this is is to just make the directory world-writable (`chmod o+w the_dir`), but this is highly insecure, allowing anyone with any kind of access to the system to store stuff there. A better solution is to either make the PHP user the owner of the directory and specify permission 700 (or 755 if you want it to be world-readable), or create a new group, put the PHP user and yourself in that group, set the group on the directory, and set permission 770 (775 for world-readability) on the directory.

Answer (score 2):

It should work, please check the users permission to the directory and/or file. 
You always can try this program writing to /tmp/my.log, it should work)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use the same fopen and fwrite functions on Linux.

The only special thing is that the folder where it's written (or at least the file itself) must be given write permissions.

An easy way to test it would be to set the file permission (or its folder) to 777.

Comment: Giving read-, write- and execution-rights to _everyone_ is a bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

fopen and fwrite works on both SO.

Probabily you have permission denied. Try to give write perms on your file on linux.
You can use php `chmod` func